# Estudo de "simulação de interação" no android

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Olá gostaria que alguém me disponibilizasse algum material(pode ser em inglês Tb) para eu estudar sobre este assunto que não sei a definição correta.
Ex: Quero que meu APP realize  interação que o usuário iria fazer no Android, como por exemplo, fazer uma pesquisa do google e pegar este resultado ou abrir um outro aplicativo.

Para isso eu usaria SHELL?

Dê preferência busco por referências que utilizem o Córdova ou algo semelhante.

Se for possível só o nome para definir isso para eu pesquisar já ajudaria muito. Pois já que não sei o nome desta técnica não sei como pesquisar.

RESUMIDAMENTE: Busco uma referencia para que eu possa abrir outros aplicativos e interagir com algumas partes deles, simulando ou automatizando assim algumas ações do usuário no Android

Agradeço =3

Comment: Vc quer que seu aplicativo chame outro aplicativo?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho  Sim basicamente isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode-se usar o `PackageManager` para obter um `Intent` para um pacote, exemplo:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.exemplo.pacote");
startActivity(intent);
```

O método `getLaunchIntentForPackage(String packageName)` retorna um `Intent` para iniciar uma Activity a partir do pacote selecionado.

Veja a documentação [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

Veja mais nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4674391/5429980).

Comment: Obrigado denner vou pesquisar mais sobre agora que tenho uma boa base